# C Code Parser for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, c, parsing

Does anyone know of any C parser library for .NET?

(I'm intending to parse C code into some form of object graph, so I can convert it to a different language.)

Comment: FYI:  The name of the "object graph" you're referring to is called an Abstract Syntax Tree, or AST.

Comment: I just have to ask - you're using .NET to compile ANSI C into what? Please say FORTRAN or Cobol. And maybe throw in some JavaScript while you're at it. =)

Comment: Hahaha I was thinking about converting to C to D, just because I'm more comfortable with some aspects of .NET compared to a native library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ANTLR can do what you'd like. It has a C preprocessor and ANSI C grammar.

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

Answer (score 5):

A proper C99 grammar is not that trivial. It's better to use a proven C parser (e.g., Clang). It is possible to use it with .NET via C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0):

**First Option**
Raw class : You can extract scanner and parser class from this application.
Part 1 : the scanner
Part 2 the parser and part 3 the main program, in this code snippet :

https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/453104/parsing-c-code-using-c