# C Parser in C# or generally .Net

Tags: c#, c, parsing

For my diploma thesis I need to implement certain static C code analysis and I am desperately looking for a framework/library that would allow me to parse C source code, split it up into single functions, for every function determine what variables are changed in the function body and derive certain annotations for the code automatically.
Is there any good framework written in C# or generally as .Net class for this purpose?

Comment: Have you considered using regular expressions?

Comment: @WhoCares: That is the fool's choice...

Comment: What you're asking for is much, while there are good tools for parsing in .NET many have their issues with the C grammar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Code Parser for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627588/c-code-parser-for-net)

Comment: I read the answer before I posted my question, I do not need a general parser/lexer, but something lightweight that is why I provided more information in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about googling for "C Parser written in C#"?

I got this as first link: http://code.google.com/p/cpp-ripper/

Also, I think the C grammar can be found in quite a lot of places, so you might just want to open up your [.NET variant of lex/yacc](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target) and go from there?

Comment: Thank you a lot, I tried to google several entries, I even went to code.google.com and searched for "C parser", but somehow I overlooked this project. It seems to be exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, the parser you suggested is a very nice, straightforward implementation in C# that is easy to tweak and to adapt for any task. I used it to parse the C code and to infer some information I needed for my implementation. The only problem is that the parsing is not reversible and since I had to modify the original code I had to use a combined parser/regexp approach, where I used parser to infer WHAT to change and the regexps to find the place WHERE to change.

Comment: Both links are 404, missing.

Answer (score 3):

You might like to check ANTLR. It comes with versions of several versions, included C and C#. There are some free grammars on [ANTLR web site](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html), including C.

Comment: Yes, I know ANTLR and I visited the site before, but it seems to be a somewhat too general and sophisticated solution for me: the topic of my thesis is static software verification, not parsers/lexers. I just need to implement the approach I suggest in the thesis and need something lightweight, like mentioned in the answer by Daren Themas.

Comment: Link is missing, 404.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem and having done a research about YACC tools for C# I have chosen Gold Parsing System with Semantic Engine. My project was parsing SQL queries and generating logical query plans (from T-SQL grammar subset).

I really recommend it. Those 2 libraries make parsing stuff painless and allow to map grammar to the object model in your code. It feels very intuitive and made my project successful :) However, it may lack some advanced ANTLR features, so recognize your needs carefully.

Gold Project http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/

Semantic Engine Lib http://code.google.com/p/bsn-goldparser

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using GPL'd code, you might want to take a look at the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) source code. If you need to do it within .Net, you can always use [p/invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to call code from the GCC libraries.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/gcc/c-parser.c?view=markup might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I used GCC as a front-end in the past in several projects, but I would like to keep my solution as simple and homogenous as possible, it's already complicated enough in the part that does not regard parsers. :)