# How to make a C-Like Interpreted Scripting Language in C#

Tags: c#, lua, interpreted-language

**Question:**
I am looking to develop a Scripting Language like Lua, but you use

```
    if (paramters) {
        codeToDo()
    }
```

rather than

```
    if parameters do
        code_to_do()
    end
```

but have yet to find a good tutorial out their on the internet.

**Parameters**:
I want it to be interpreted, and I also want to make it in C#, so that it integrates with it the easiest.

Comment: So what is your question? We help when you are stuck, not to do your research and write the program for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992068/c-parser-in-c-sharp-or-generally-net

Comment: You may wish to look at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn and http://scriptcs.net/, perhaps you don't need to create something new

Comment: Another alternative is [CSScript](http://www.csscript.net/). I use it extensively for all my scripting needs.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a language and an interpreter is not an easy task, you have to define the complete syntax and after write a parser for it, finally you have to implement a interpreter capable of executing your language.

There are already answers about creating programming languages here on SO:

- [Suggestions for writing a programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453870/suggestions-for-writing-a-programming-language)
- [How would you go about writing a simple programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091887/how-would-you-go-about-writing-a-simple-programming-language)

Some books that could guide you in the right direction:

- [Language Implementation Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435645X)
  " Written by Terrence Parr creator of ANTLR a parse generation tool in Java, teaches the basics of language definition and the implementation of a bytecode vm."
- [Writing Compilers and Interpreters: A Software Engineering Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470177071)

  Couldnt find a practical book with code in C#, most of books about compilers comes with code in C, only some with Java.

Comment: Thanks! It's alright that you couldn't find one in C#, because C# and Java have incredibly similar syntax/practices. Therefore, it shouldn't be hard to convert.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck with this project, It surely is a hard one to complete but you can learn a lot in the process. Keep focused and who knows, probably in some time we're going to see a tag with your language right here.